# Base64 Image redirection problem on Drupal integrated with Cloudfront

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, drupal-7, amazon-cloudfront, drupal-8

I am receiving some issues on Drupal.

I have integrated Amazon cloudfront with Drupal.

The Cloudfront origin for my domain is drupal.example.com and Cnames are www.example.com and example.com.

The problem is that some images are 
are forming the URL's like this

> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7

Please suggest.

Comment: Where is the issue ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499633/how-to-display-base64-images-in-html

Comment: What is the question? What version of Drupal?